# An attempt to attach an auto-named database : No satisfactory Answer

Tags: vb.net

I have the following connection string : `konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Skedulering6\Skedulering6\SkeduleringsDatabasis6.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`

However I get the following error (which on previous test runs was not a problem) :   `Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Skedulering6\Skedulering6\SkeduleringsDatabasis6.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.`

I have looked everywhere and am now truly confused. Any help would be much appreciated. Regards

Comment: Just give a name to that database. So it will not be attached again if it already exists.

Comment: Thank you Steve. How would I change my connection string?  Is'nt my data base already called SkeduleringDatabasis6?

Comment: Hi Steve, I have changed my connection string to :konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Skedulering6\Skedulering6\SkeduleringsDatabasis6.mdf;Integrated Security=True" Now I get the error : Additional information: Cannot open database "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Skedulering6\Skedulering6\SkeduleringsDatabasis6.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\Administrator'.

Comment: Okay I have used : konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source = .\ SQLEXPRESS;Database=SkeduleringsDatabasis6;Integrated Security=TRUE" It stills say cannot open database login failed, I am utterly stumped. Please can someone help me?